# use bash to update a files date/time stamp

Tags: bash, macos, shell, unix

I would like to use this code snippet to update a files date and time stamp using there file name:

Example file names:

```
2009.07.04-03.42.01.mov
2019.06.08-01.12.08.mov
```

I get the following error "The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “touch: out of range or illegal time specification: [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS]”

How would I modify this code snippet?

```
for if in "$@"
do
 date_Time=$(echo "$if" | awk '{ print substr( $0, 1, length($0)-7 ) }' | sed 's/\.//g' | sed 's/-//')
  touch -t "$date_Time" "$if"
done
```

UPDATE (01/05/2022):......
I would also like the code to work for the following filename formats...

And file names with no time info (time would default to 12pm):

```
2009.07.04.mov
2019.06.08.mov
```

And file names with description info:

```
2009.07.04-file-description.mov
2019.06.08-video-file info.mp4
2019.06.08-video-old-codec.avi
```

Comment: Your code works for me, albeit clumsily. How exactly did you run your script? You need to pass the names of the files you want to modify as command-line arguments, with no leading path.

Comment: You did not post the content of your variables `date_Time` and `if` at the point where the error occurs, so it is difficult to say what's going wrong. I suggest that you run your loop with `set -x` turned on. Perhaps one of the files has a slightly different name pattern than you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message suggests that you passed in file names which do not match your examples.  Perhaps modify your code to display an error message if it is called with no files at all, and remove the path if it is passed files with directory names.

As an aside, `if` is a keyword, so you probably don't want to use it as a variable name, even though it is possible.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# == 0 ]; then
    echo "Syntax: $0 files ..." >&2
    exit 1
fi

for f in "$@"
do
    date_Time=$(echo "$f" | awk '{ sub(/.*\//, ""); gsub(/[^0-9]+/, ""); print substr( $0, 1, length($0)-7 ) }')
    touch -t "$date_Time" "$if"
done
```

Notice also how I factored out the `sed` scripts; Awk can do everything `sed` can do, so I included the final transformation in the main script. (As an aside, `sed 's/[-.]//g'` would do both in one go; or you could do `sed -e 's/\.//' -e 's/-//'` with a single `sed` invocation.)

If you use Bash, you could simplify this further:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# == 0 ]; then
    echo "Syntax: $0 files ..." >&2
    exit 1
fi

for f in "$@"
do
    base=${f##*/}
    dt=${base//[!0-9]/}
    dt=${dt:0:12}
    case $dt in
      [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])
         touch -t "$dt" "$f";;
      *) echo "$0: $f did not seem to contain a valid date ($dt)" >&2;;
    esac
done
```

Notice also how the code now warns if it cannot extract exactly 14 digits from the file name.  The [parameter expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) are somewhat clumsy but a lot more efficient than calling Awk on each file name separately (and the Awk code wasn't particularly elegant or robust either anyway).

Comment: In bash, where would there be an ambiguity, when you use a reserved name such as `if` as variable name? Even cases such as `if=xxx` or `printenv if` would do no harm.

Comment: It works fine, it's just weird.

Comment: I was wondering if you could modify the above code so that it will also allow filenames formatted with only the date?  such as... 2008.10.25.mp4 or 2021.10.25.mov       I was thinking about adding a second case statement that would match 8 numbers instead of 12.

Comment: None of that should be hard, basically add the case like you say and `touch -t "${dt}0000" "$f";;`

Comment: I added the code above but it doesn't always update the created time, just the modification time. -->
for f in "$@"
do
    base=${f##*/}
    dt=${base//[!0-9]/}
    dt2=${base//[!0-9]/}
    dt=${dt:0:12}
    dt2=${dt2:0:8}
    case $dt in
      [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])
         touch -t "$dt" "$f";;
      *) echo "$0: $f did not seem to contain a valid date ($dt)" >&2;;
    esac
    case $dt2 in
      [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])
         touch -t "${dt2}0000" "$f";;
    esac
done <--

Comment: How do I add code to comments so it isn't jumbled up?

Comment: Usually just don't post code in comments. If you have to, \`code\`  formatting lets you use crude monospace code formatting, but no line breaks etc. You want to add the eight-digit branch inside the existing `case` statement before the `*)` case, not add an entire new `case` structure.

Comment: Maybe see also https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/The_case_statement for an explanation of the `case` syntax.

Comment: `case $dt in
      [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])
         touch -t "$dt" "$f";;
[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])          touch -t "${dt}0000" "$f";;` etc

Answer (score 1):

#### Quick and small bash function

```
setDateFileFromName() {
    local _file _dtime
    for _file ;do
        _dtime="${_file%.*.mov}"
        _dtime="${_dtime##*/}"
        touch -t ${_dtime//[!0-9]/} "$_file"
    done
}
```

Then

```
setDateFileFromName /path/to store dir/????.??.??-??.??.??.mov
```

Remark. This work with filenames formated as your sample. Any change in filename format will break this!

Comment: Note: `for file ;do` is shortcut to `for file in "$@" ;do `!